# How to Authenticate and Authorize Asp.Net Web application through QuickBooks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

how to Authenticate and Authorize Asp.Net Web application through QuickBooks.
I want to integrate QuickBooks Accounts System in ASP.NET web Application I have successfully make developer account on quickbooks and make an app and got consumer key, consumer Secret and App Token and all URL's 
Know I need some asp.net web api code snipped to successfully authenticate and authorize my web user's and than show there accounting detail 
Please help me i Google alot but have no success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Strange this form is 0% active related to quickbooks API's or etc, after alot of struggling i found an answer of above mention question,
Download Quickbooks IPP.NET SDK it will provide you different classes for CURD.

```
 var appToken = "";
        var consumerKey = "";
        var consumerSecret = "";
        // the above 3 fields you can get when create your app on quickbook go to My app----> select youre app--->goto KEYS
        var accessToken = "";
        var accessTokenSecret = "";
        // this two tookens you will get from URL on the same above page
        var realmId = "1400728630";   //1400728630
        // this is youre company ID which can be used when you create youre          //company on freshbook
        var serviceType = IntuitServicesType.QBO;

        var validator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        var context = new ServiceContext(appToken,realmId, serviceType, validator);
        var service = new DataService(context);


        try
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            //Mandatory Fields
            customer.GivenName = "Mary";
            customer.Title = "Ms.";
            customer.MiddleName = "Jayne";
            customer.FamilyName = "Cooper";
            service.AddAsync(customer);
            //service.Add(entity);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```